# Prepared statements for data out of a database

Tags: php, security, mysqli, sql-injection

When users first make an account on my website, they enter their username and password, these are both put though a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections. But later down the line I will grab the username from the database and use that in a query. Is this still leaving me open to an attack? Do I need to use a prepared statement for this query as well? Do I need to use a prepared statement for all user inputted information out of a database even though it has already gone through a prepared statement when first entered? Is it safe to assume that all data put through a prepared statement when first entered is safe?

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid using a prepared statement? It is only a few more characters/lines of code, and keeps your coding consistent.

Comment: There isn't, I'm just curious if the data is still dangerous.

Comment: Yes, it can be. A username of `sam' or 1=1` could cause issues in the query. or even simply `o'riely` could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must always use prepared statement with **parameter binding**.

Prepared statements are not a magical dust that cure SQL injection. They don't even prevent SQL injection. Prepared statements let you use **parameter binding**. It is this separation of SQL and data that protects you from SQL injection.

**Insecure prepared statement:**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM park WHERE id=$id");
$stmt->execute();
```

Because you are still injecting variables into SQL directly you are vulnerable to SQL injection. It doesn't matter where the content of these variables come from; it is the fact that you use unknown values in SQL that makes it vulnerable.

**Secure prepared statement:**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM park WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

As you can see I used a placeholder and then method called `bind_param()`. This way the variable is separated form the SQL and there is no way that the SQL will ever changed. No matter what value will be passed in `$id`, the SQL will stay constant.